How to disable all buttons when a request is sent to the server
How can I disable all the buttons in the page, when a request, like a POST or a GET request, is sent and being processed? (BTW, I'm no talking about asynchronous requests).
I used beforeunload event listener to disable all the btns in the page, because as I said earlier the requests are not async, which means when sent, a full page reload or even the url change will occur. So, the event listener executes and it works fine unless when getting back to the page using BFcache, btns remain disabled on that case.
Here another way I tried, but still doesn't work when using BFcache.
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", disableButtons);
}


Here another way I tried ... except you forgot to show what disableButtons actually does, so perhaps you're doing something wrong™

btns remain disabled on that case - have you considered enabling the btns on page load?

" I'm no talking about asynchronous request", pretty sure you are. If this is standard request and not a SPA, the page would redirect and you don't have to worry about the buttons at that point.

@Phix not when you're on a slow network ig, I've tried it on Slow 3G, and I could click the btn twice to send the exact request twice

@JaromandaX Well I did, and I think that works. I disable all the btns on beforeunload, and on Domcontentloaded I enable all of them, except some btns that I don't wanna enable them at first, so I filter them like this: document.querySelectorAll("button:not([disabledatfirst])");

@JaromandaX actually disableButtons function just disables the btns, nothing complicated

Your question would be easier to answer if you show ALL relevant code - i.e. exactly how you disable AND attempt and fail to enable the buttons

I'd do this by adding an event listener to when the form has been submitted. This allows you to use methods like GET, POST, etc.
The code:
let formId = document.getElementById("YourFormId");
formId.addEventListener("submit", ()=>{
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   buttons[i].disabled = true;
} 
})


IS this answer good?

Yep! almost the thing I've wanted.
